# getting corresponding date for the max(hourvalue) in table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
 SELECT [Id]
  ,[Date]
  ,[Condition]
         FROM [CRESULTS]
 where condition = 'abc'
```

I need to find the maxvalue of hour13  and the corresponding date, so far the query i wrote works, But any other alterative ideas?

```
  SELECT top 1 max(abs([Hour13])) as hour13,date
  FROM CRESULTS where condition ='a' and Date between '2011-05-16' and '2011-07-10'
    group date
   order by hour13 desc
```

Comment: Your query is not valid SQL and I can't imagine that it runs as you have it without an error. Did you intend to have a GROUP BY clause?

Comment: I think yo umean select max(hour13), DATE FROM [CRESULTS]
 where condition = 'abc' group by date ?

Comment: Yes i did, I was trying to edit and looks like it got lost in it :  SELECT top 1 max(abs([Hour13])) as hour13,date   FROM CRESULTS where condition ='a' and Date between '2011-05-16' and '2011-07-10'     group by date    order by hour13 desc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `MAX` here.

```
SELECT  TOP 1
        ABS(hour13) AS abs_hour13,
        datefield
FROM    cresults
WHERE   condition = 'a'
        AND datefield BETWEEN '2011-05-16' AND '2011-07-10'
ORDER BY
        abs_hour13 DESC
```